# Restrict client from allocating objects on heap C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I have a class `X` and method `addX()` which allocates objects of `X` on the heap. I want to restrict client-code from directly allocating objects of `X` (so that the `X *ptr = new X` is not allowed).

I've declared `new`, `new[]` operators private, but since I'm allocating `X's objects` through `addX()` I need to define them (operators). So, what's their definition should look like?

Comment: Could you give a more complete (pseudo) code example of what you're trying to achieve please. Also you should elaborate on your use case and why you actually need that restriction.

Comment: I'm developing a framework which handles all objects internally. the user just has to call addThis() or removeThat() etc.

Comment: @ibe Have you considered turning off creation altogether by making constructor (and maybe destructor) `private`, and only provide a `public` member function that creates your objects?  If you want control over how your objects are created, that would be the simplest thing to do, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Hide the constructors, use a factory function:

```
class A
{
public:
    static A* create() { return new A; }
    static void destroy(A* a) { delete a; }
protected:
   A() {}
   A(const A&) {}
   A& operator=(const A&) {}
};
```

Comment: This is the canonical way this is achieved (and doesn't involve implementing `new`), although you should consider only defining `create` and returning a smart pointer to avoid having to implement `destroy` and risking callers leaking the allocated memory.

Comment: I'd make the constructors `private` or apply `final`, this uses the non-virtual `~A()`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

class X {
public:
    static void addX()
    {
        X* p1 = new X;
        delete p1;
    }
private:
    void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
    {
        std::cout << "custom new for size " << sz << '\n';
        return ::operator new(sz);
    }
    void* operator new[](std::size_t sz)
    {
        return ::operator new(sz);
    }
};

int main()
{
    X::addX();
}
```

Comment: This permits creating instances of `X` on the stack (ie: `X x;` is valid).